# Nginx конфигурация не работает

Tags: nginx, api, flask, config

Есть некоторый `location` в конфе `nginx`:

```
location /ctftime {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8011$request_uri;
}
```

То-есть, у меня на сервере локально поднята связка `Python + Flask` и хотелось бы, чтобы при `request` на `https://xxx.ru/ctftime` был `proxy_pass` на непосредственно `http://localhost:8011$request_uri`.

Сама связка работает, это подтверждает `curl http://localhost:8011/ctftime/teams/get/top/2020/50`, которая возвращает верный результат запроса.

При запросе же `https://xxx.ru/ctftime/teams/get/top/2020/50` я получаю либо редирект на корень, либо `500`.

Ну и полный конфиг на всякий случай:

```
server {
    server_name xxx.ru  www.xxx.ru;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.ru/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        return 301 https://yyy.xxx.ru/;
    }

    location /zalgo {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/zalgo;
    }

    location /ctftime {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8011$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name xxx.ru www.xxx.ru;

    if ($host = xxx.ru) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = www.xxx.ru) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: просто `proxy_pass http://localhost:8011;`

Comment: Хм. А почему это работает? `nginx` сразу с `$request_uri` проксирует?

Comment: я рекомендую прочесть [документацию](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), секцию `URI запроса передаётся на сервер так:`. в общих чертах объяснение конкретно этого кейса такое: при проксировании запроса не требуется изменения URL запроса (подтверждается "передачей" $request_uri без всяких изменений `proxy_pass http://localhost:8011$request_uri;`), это значит, что нужно пойти по дефолтной логике директивы proxy_pass